# How to animate the color of the whole screen (all visible views/layouts) when changing to NightMode in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-night-mode

I know there is `ObjectAnimator / ValueAnimator` for [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) in Android, and also one can set the system-wide night mode with `UiModeManager.setNightMode(int)`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager#setNightMode(int)

How could we make a color animation when switching from DayMode to NightMode? (Currently I'm using the latest Huawei phone and find no animation there, not sure if other Android phone has this feature?)

Answer (score 1):

try using MotionLayout with keyTrigger

check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout#keytrigger

Comment: Thx for ur quick answer, I just read some tutorials but not quite get it.. could u elaborate a bit how I can achieve my goal with MotionLayout?

Comment: I wrote a simple example, hope it helps :), see the gist: https://gist.github.com/AbdoNasr3/95a3f0763c37afe51dc56a5d1dd2fc2c                       Note: no need for Using KeyTrigger, I was Just mistaken about purpose of your question

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think the best you can do is create a light and dark theme for your app in the style.xml file.

[here](https://gist.github.com/bapspatil/1880128456ff83e456f4033c3316dbaa) is a github link of someone who achieved this with a simple code example. there is even a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps0phswbHls&feature=youtu.be) of how it will look.

it seems like the animation is some android default fade_in/fade_out anim but personally i think it looks nice enough. let me know if this works for you